# Karma and Angular2 - Mixing Isolated and non-isolated tests causes runtime injection failure

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I am trying to create a model to back an Angular 2 app. I am new to Angular2, so please bear with me.

The model is a port from an older Java code base that we want to move to TypeScript. In doing so, we are recreating tests that would be classified as ["isolated" test](https://angular.io/guide/testing#isolated-unit-tests).

## Issue:

After adding an isolated test, **all** Angular2 tests from the seed fail with similar errors in Karma:

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Home should have a title FAILED
    Failed: Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    Error: Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
        at syntaxError (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1540:21 <- config/spec-bundle.js:33745:34) [ProxyZone]
        at webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:14542:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:46747:40 [ProxyZone]
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [ProxyZone]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:14524:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:46729:54) [ProxyZone]
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25630:25 <- config/spec-bundle.js:57835:66) [ProxyZone]
...snip...
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70398:43) [<root> => ProxyZone]
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:69881:34) [<root>]
        at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:69911:42) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70438:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:593:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70866:35) [<root>]
        at <anonymous> [<root>]
    Error: Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
        at syntaxError (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1540:21 <- config/spec-bundle.js:33745:34) [ProxyZone]
        at webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:14542:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:46747:40 [ProxyZone]
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [ProxyZone]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:14524:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:46729:54) [ProxyZone]
...snip...
        at Function.TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:610:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:17189:29) [ProxyZone]
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/home/home.component.spec.ts:43:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73448:37) [ProxyZone]
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70169:39) [ProxyZone]
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70398:43) [<root> => ProxyZone]
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:69883:34) [<root>]
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/home/home.component.spec.ts:54:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73459:22)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70638:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70169:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70637:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70398:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:69883:34)
```

I have left out more errors as they are all similar for each spec file: https://github.com/Nava2/angular-starter/tree/master/src/app. The full log output is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Nava2/72a29a8bdd4f75cfb89349726f7724a2).

Here is the WebStorm tree:

[image: WebStorm Test Tree]

If I remove the isolated test, there is no more errors with Angular2 tests.

## Reproducible steps:

1. Clone this fork: https://github.com/Nava2/angular-starter
2. Run, `npm install`
3. Run, `npm run test`

If I remove `app/model/entity.no-testbed.spec.ts`, the errors disappear. I'm unsure why they are happening. If this is not the way I should develop this, please let me know as I don't want to waste time down a "poorly practiced path."

## Misc Information

- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the source code for your spec file.  It sounds like you haven't imported HomeComponent yet.

Comment: No, that's not it. You can see the spec files here: https://github.com/Nava2/angular-starter/tree/master/src/app